# vuejs deep watching for model change

Tags: vuejs2, watch

I have a problem watching for changes in my model. I need a deep watch of a model but my watch is not triggered:

```
    data: {
          formModel: Form.init({}),

          },

watch: {
    formModel: {

        handler: function (newValue) {

            console.log("Modified")

        },

        deep: true
    }
},
```

My watch is never triggered.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: What is `Form.init` and what does it return?

Comment: Can you create a working example of your problem using a codepen, jsbin or any other site.